# ReactPHP: What is the difference between terminate process and close process?

Tags: php, process, reactphp

Using the reactphp/child-process library,

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$process = new React\ChildProcess\Process(...some long proccess..);

$process->on('exit', function($exitCode, $termSignal) {
    // ...
});

$process->start($loop);


$loop->run();
```

to kill the process should I use `$process->close()` or `$process->terminate()` ?

Whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*terminate()* - This method call proc_terminate method, and you can send custom signal. By default proc_terminate send **SIGTERM**, but you can send another signal, for example **SIGSTOP** or **SIGKILL**

*close()* - This method close descriptors and call proc_close. $this->process set null, and write exit code in $this->exitCode

If you need stop child process - call *close()*